# How to Navigate through Bottom Navigation (GNav) in Flutter. Normal Way getting stuck on CallBack

Tags: flutter, navigation, bottomnavigationview

I am using GoogleNavBar in my flutter project where I have created a sepeare file for this. Now I have three pages I want to navigate through. I am used the normal method of making Scafold widget and passing bottom navigation and then simply changing index and passing it to body. But this method is getting stuck at CallBack.

```
Code for Bottom Navigation (have`enter code here` commented out the Scafold method): 
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_literals_to_create_immutables, prefer_const_constructors, camel_case_types, prefer_typing_uninitialized_variables, prefer_final_fields
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:google_nav_bar/google_nav_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:seva/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:seva/screens/notificationsPage.dart';
import 'package:seva/screens/welcome_screen.dart';

class botNav extends StatefulWidget {
  const botNav({super.key});
  // final Function(int) onTabChange;

  @override
  State<botNav> createState() => _botNavState();
}

class _botNavState extends State<botNav> {
  List<Widget> _pages = [
    NotificationPage(),
    home_screen(),
    NotificationPage(),
  ];
  int _currentIndex = 1;
  @override
  // Create a list of pages that you want to navigate to
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GNav(
      gap: 10,
      activeColor: Colors.blue,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),

      // Tabs are the elements at the bottom
      onTabChange: (index) {
        setState(() {
          _currentIndex = index;
          
          HapticFeedback.lightImpact();
        });
      },
      selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
      tabs: [
        GButton(
          icon: CupertinoIcons.profile_circled,
          text: 'Profile',
        ),
        GButton(icon: CupertinoIcons.home, text: 'Home'),
        GButton(icon: CupertinoIcons.bell, text: 'Notifications'),
      ],
    );
    // body: _pages.elementAt(_currentIndex),
  }
}
```

In homescreen I am using stack so I thought this might be creating problem but even the navigation route is not working with other files.
Code for HomeScreen:

```
// ignore_for_file: unused_local_variable, non_constant_identifier_names, unused_field, prefer_final_fields, unused_element
// ignore_for_file: unused_import, camel_case_types, prefer_const_constructors

import 'package:curved_navigation_bar/curved_navigation_bar.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart'; // Use this import for SVG support
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:seva/Provider/auth_provider.dart';
import 'package:seva/routes/routes.dart';
import 'package:seva/screens/welcome_screen.dart';
import 'package:seva/widgets/app_drawer.dart';
import 'package:seva/screens/notificationsPage.dart';
import 'package:seva/widgets/customButton.dart';
import 'package:seva/widgets/custom_botNav.dart';

class home_screen extends StatefulWidget {
  const home_screen({super.key});

  @override
  State<home_screen> createState() => _homeScreenState();
}

class _homeScreenState extends State<home_screen> {
  int _currentIndex = 1;
  // void _onTabChange(int index) {
  //   setState(() {
  //     _currentIndex = index;
  //   });
  // }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final List<String> daily_quotes = [
      "assets/screen1.png",
    ];

    return Scaffold(
      bottomNavigationBar: botNav(),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: size.height * .45,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 6.0),
            child: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Image(
                    image: AssetImage("assets/screen1.png"),
                    width: double.infinity,
                    height: 260,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: GridView.count(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                      children: [
                        createCard(context, "Water", 'assets/water.svg'),
                        createCard(context, "Guru Nanak Free Clinic",
                            'assets/clinic.svg'),
                        createCard(
                            context, "Blood Donation", 'assets/blood.svg'),
                        createCard(
                            context, "Sanjay Gas Seva", 'assets/sanjay.svg'),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: double.infinity,
                    child: customButton(
                        text: 'Donate Now',
                        onPressed: () {
                          Navigator.pushReplacement(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const welcomeScreen(),
                            ),
                          );
                        }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget createCard(BuildContext context, String title, String iconPath) {
    return Card(
      elevation: 4.0,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
      ),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          // Handle the card click event here
        },
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              SvgPicture.asset(
                iconPath,
                height: 45.0, // Set the height as needed
                color: Colors.blue, // Change the color to your preference
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 8.0),
              Text(
                title,
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 16.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```